# Adding a new HDD into a Debian box and partition it

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, partition

I have a Debian Squeeze 6.0 box running an SVN hosting service all in a single HDD.

I have this important folder that I would want to transfer to the new HDD:

- /backups

For the moment, this folder is into my single HDD with all the other system folders.

I would like to add a new sata HDD and transfer /backups into the new HDD so the backup files, which takes a lot of GB, are separate from the system files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite easy:

- format the new HDD with the partition table you wish (probably just one partition in your case), and put your favourite filesystem on it
- transfer all data from your /backup to your new HDD
- edit your fstab so that your new HDD will be mounted on /backup
- voila.

Comment: What is the purpore of the fstab file ?

Comment: It's used to inform startup scripts which (also how) and where to mount the partitions.